# I have three computers, each with Gb and 2.5Gb NICs. I want to parallel network the Gb and 2.5Gb NICs Any howtos?

Tags: networking

I have two NAS servers and my working desktop and each has 2 NICs, one Gb and one 2.5Gb.  Currently each is networked through the Gb NIC to the internet, I would like to establish a 2.5Gb parallel network that contains only the 2.5Gb NICs from the three computers in the net for fast file retrieval between the three computers only.  I have a 2.5Gb switch to connect the three 2.5Gb NICs. The two NAS servers do not necessarily need to be on the public-facing internet.

Any Howtos?  Been searching the internet for this use case and have come up empty.

Networks Diagram:

Private (Local) Network. No internet access. Fast File Transfer.

```
CP1 (Win11) 2.5Gb NIC---------\

CP2 (Win11) 2.5Gb NIC-------- 2.5Gb Switch

CP3 (Ubuntu)2.5Gb NIC---------/
```

Parallel public facing internet

```
CP1 1Gb NIC ---- 1Gb Switch -------- Router -- Modem --- Internet
```

Reading the answer to another similar question, could this accomplish what I want?

```
CP1 (Win11) 2.5Gb NIC-------\

CP2 (Win11) 2.5Gb NIC------ 2.5Gb Switch---1Gb Switch--modem

CP3 (Ubuntu)2.5Gb NIC-------/
```

disable the 1gB NICs
and then blank the default gateway for CP2 and 3 (the NAS server) so that they will not "see" the internet.

I think that this would provide fast, non-internet-facing NASs for my working computer without exposing the NAss to the internet.  Am I right?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What OS do the systems run?

Answer (score 1):

To use your example diagrams, you could do this for separation:

```
                /------1Gb CP1 (Win11)  2.5Gb-------\
modem--1Gb Switch------1Gb CP2 (Win11)  2.5Gb------ 2.5Gb Switch
                           CP3 (Ubuntu) 2.5Gb-------/
```

Set the 2.5 Gb interfaces to `10.0.0.[1,2,3]` with no gateway, and the 1 Gb interfaces to `192.168.0.[1,2]` for example, and windows will generally understand that it can only reach your NAS using the 2.5 Gb network. You may have to manually `route add` if it's stubborn.

---

That said, most NAS devices will struggle to hit 2.5 Gbps (300+MB/s disk IO). You can probably stick to just the 2.5G connection and only try the above if you're maxing it out.

Comment: This worked 100%.  Thanks

Comment: @dstarke consider marking it as the answer if it helped, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well - assuming you're ok with using static IPs, just set each system on the the 'fast' network with a separate IP static IP in a different range from your main network. Don't set a default gateway, and access each device on the network by IP.

Depending on the OS, there *may* be some performance tuning needed - things like setting jumbo packets has a positive effect on speeds on multigig networks.

*If* internet stops working, you'd need to mess with the metrics of each interface to prioritise the 1GB network over the 2.5 gig one cause some OSes prioritise the fastest interface first.

Comment: Windows does not like having one adapter on one subnet and another adapter on a different subnet. Author likely would be better served purchasing a modem that has a 2.5GB LAN port, connect that to the switch, and extend the network from there

Comment: I'm running a network like that, actually with 2 parallel networks for testing, with different subnets. It works fine! My main PC runs windows, and I've had various things hanging off it. I also run my 'own' subnet, so if you count connecting to wifi to use the printer on the main subnet, I've gone as far as 3 subnets

Comment: I just know Windows complained the last time I tried connecting a Windows 10 machine to 192.168.3.2 and 192.169.4.2 indicating it was on the 3rd or 4th floor. I also didn’t have network connection to one or the other subnet but my use case was slightly different

Comment: Added another possible topology to the question above.  Will this accomplish what I want?

Comment: they'd be on the same network. Windows *would* prefer the 2.5 gig network for everything. Having a seperate, non internet connected network makes more sense here